# How to create a menu where the user can sort blocks of data on parameter-values?

Tags: python, sorting, object, parameters, menu

## My program so far:

User gets 3 questions:

---

Mortgage rate:

Downpayment:

Interest deduction:

---

The input from theese questions is saved to variables.

Next: A textfile containing data of property-listings is opened in the program.py. I use the data (for example: price of each property, rent etc) to calculate monthly rate and square meter price for each property. Then I write this data in to the textfile (using writelines function) so these values is saved for every block of data (for every property). Then I print out the data for all property-listings to the user.

Now the output-screen is like this (with example-input from user):

---

Mortgage rate(in percent): 2

Downpayment(in swedish SEK, i.e kr): 100000

Interest deduction(in percent): 20

All listed properties:

Size: 655000

Price: 35

Rent: 1200

Phonenr: 0716-257681

Adress: Blablastreet2

Monthly rate: 1940.0

Price/Squaremeter: 18714.285714285714

"emptyline"

Size: 11840950

Price: 80

Rent: 3550

Phonenr: 08-6601502

Adress: Yadayadastreet3

Monthly rate: 19204.6

Price/Squaremeter: 148011.875

etc for all properties..

---

What i want to do:
Above the "All listed properties:" I want there to be an option to go to a menu, like:

---

(1) Menu

---

Then pressing 1 and enter I want the user to come to a new screen with the following options

---

```
    0 - Quit
    1 - Go back to show all listed properties
    2 - Change wanted monthly rate (<200000kr)
    3 - Change wanted rent (<500000kr)
    4 - Price/squaremeter (<100000)
    5 - Change wanted size (>20kvm)
    6 - Create selection
```

---

Where the values in parenthesis is the current "standard choice"

---

When pressing for example (1) I want there to be a question such as

---

The monthly rate should be not more than (in kr):

---

And after input I want the user to come back to the menu above, but now with the new value the user put in to the question in parenthesis.
When the user is done adjusting the parameters he/she clicks on (5) to create the selection. And then I want all the property listings to be sorted after the property-parameters chosen and to be printed for the user one property at the time from lowest to highest value, where the user can go back and forth (or again choose to go to the menu).

Info about how the data from the txt-file is setup:
All parameters values are brought into the program via rows from a text-file and then sorted into different lists were every list-element represents a row of data from the textfile. There is the same row-distances from every same datapoint, meaning there is 8 rows from rent on property one to rent on property two, and in this way I have hardcoded the same data-category from every property to a list of its own, forexample prices[] or rents[].

---

Now, how to I make this happen?

(My thoughts have been: Should I create the menu with if statements in the program.py and then link them to a class containing objects for every choice in the menu somehow, where the methodfunctions are doing the sorting? How do I save the choices to the menu, in parenthesis, seems wrong to do it in a textfile like I have done with the property-data(?). How do I create new sides to go back and forth from, to the menu and back and to changing values?) I am very new to programming and python so excuse me if I am not totally clear in what I want to do here, please ask questions if you want me clarify something.

Comment: Your question is how to display menus and data on screen? I have used WConio for "command line GUI". But why don't you program some GUI with wxPython, pyQT or other GUI framework?

Comment: Partly. Specifically how to create a menu from which the user can change parameter-values which then sorts a set of data from a list based on the change of parameters, and prints them out one by one. I have not come to learning about GUI yet, is there away to do it without it? How whould you go about it then?

Comment: Look, there are many ways to reach your target. I would go for a GUI. It is so easy. I have started with wxPython and for drawing a GUI I have used boa constructor. You draw your user interface and then assign methods to buttons. Try it out it, is easy and there are many tutorials.